# C# Weird behavior after error handling in StreamWriter "using" block

Tags: c#, try-catch, streamwriter

I have C# code that collects data from csv files, and writes it out in a certain way to another csv file. The user has an option to sort or not sort (sorting does some other stuff too), based on state of a checkbox called "sortBox." Most of the work happens inside a *using* block for a StreamWriter. Within the block, there is a step where it writes to a dictionary.

There is a corner case where sorting makes the dictionary think there is a duplicate value, and an error occurs. The corner case is not worth fixing, and since not sorting is not a big deal, I am trying to offer an option when dictionary error occurs for SW to uncheck sortBox, go back to the start of the method, and write out the unsorted data. Note that the output file has one of two names, depending on whether data are sorted or not. I am fine with having both files, the sorted on never getting written to due to the error, and the unsorted one getting written to.

This is a compact version of my lame attempt. The recursive call might be a dumb idea -- and maybe the reason for the odd behavior I will describe,  but I do not know what other approach to take.

```
    void CollectAndStreamStats(string readFolder, string writeFolder)
{
//<stuff>
try
{
      using (StreamWriter csvOut = new StreamWriter(fullPath))
    {
        //<stuff>
        if (sortBox.Checked)
        {
        //<stuff>
            Try
            {
                resultsDictionary.Add(keyString, str);   //THIS IS WHAT I AM ERROR CHECKING
            }
            catch (ArgumentException e)  //OH  NO, CANNOT ADD TO DICTIONARY, UNCHECKING SORT CHECK BOX SHOULD SOLVE IT
            {
            d = MessageBoc.Show(“You’re screwed, do you want to uncheck sort option and analyze again?”,”Sucker”, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,other options)
                if (d==DialogResult.Yes)
            {
            csvOut.Close();   //CLOSE STREAM CREATED BY STREAMWRITER 
              sortBox.Checked = false;   //UNCHECK THE BOX, SHOULD WORK OK NOW. (CORNER CASE THING).
            CollectAndStreamStats(csvReadFolder, csvWriteFolder);
            }  //RUN THIS SAME METHOD ALL OVER AGAIN, BUT WITH THAT CHECK BOX UNCHECKED. NOTE THAT CSVoUT WILL HAVE A DIFFERENT NAME AND STREAMING WILL BE TO NEW FILE 
        }
    // **Loop for csvOut.WriteLine goes here if sortBox is checked. It happens elsewhere if it is unchecked.**
    } 
}
catch (IOException e)
{      
        MessageBox.Show("Well, I tried ::shrug::");
}
```

Well, some of it works. It unchecks `sortBox` -- local variables confirm this, as does UI -- compiles the unsorted data, and creates and writes to the second (unsorted) file. But then -- despite `sortBox.checked` being false, it enters the "if (`sortBox.Checked`)" loop, decides that the file name is the original sorted one again, and tries to write to it, only to throw an error saying it cannot write a closed stream.

No luck with online searches. There must be a right way, any thoughts?

Thanks much in advance,
Aram

Comment: Question:  Why are you opening a stream that you never use?  All you do is close it.    Additionally I recommend you do all the logic you can *outside* of the using block.   Don't put UI interaction (i.e. dialogs) inside of that block.  Have your data ready to write when it comes time to write it.  Then, just use the using block to write it out, not to put up dialogs.

Comment: You could just add a `return;` after your call to CollectAndStreamStats to exit the method immediately.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. Joe, I did not include csvOut.WriteLine steps in my stripped-down example, because I thought they were peripheral to my bad programming issue :P. I assure you I use them in my actual code. Joe and Klaus, what you say makes a lot of sense, and I will redo it based on your recommendations. Much appreciated.